# Internal Server Error in Dropbox from Android

Tags: java, android, dropbox

Tried on Dropbox forum but no luck:

I'm reaching Dropbox API from Android,

i do a HttpPost request to "https://api.dropbox.com/0/fileops/create_folder" and i pass as parameters:

```
List <NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("path", "xxx"));
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("root", "xxx"));
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_consumer_key", "xxx"));
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_token", "xxx"));
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_secret", "xxx"));
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_timestamp", "xxx"));
parameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_nonce", "xxx"));
```

And well, the thing is i get an Internal Server Error although with the same code (different parameters, of course) i manage to authenticate. Any idea why?

Comment: When you say "different parameters" do you mean different parameter *names* or *values*?

Comment: Both of them, diff parameters and diff values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create folder please use this code

```
 private DropboxAPI api = new DropboxAPI();

Entry entry = api.createFolder("dropbox", "NameOfFolder");
```

with  [dropbox-android-sdk-0.1](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/dropbox-android-sdk-0.1.tar.gz)

Hope it helps you.

Comment: In this way, i have you use the Dropbox library, i wanted to access the API directly. Thanks for the response anyway, it seems i'll have to do that because not even in the Dropbox forums someone could give me a single answer.

Answer (score 0):

I may have not understood quite well your problem but why do you need different parameter names? Often in this kind of requests you need the exact parameter name.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: No, i mean that i can log in just fine and that is in this case, uploading files or creating directories, when "it breaks".